# Accessing data from a $firebaseobject based on data from another $firebaseobject

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I have the following structure on Firebase.

```
+Groups
  -group1
    -groupMessage: abc
    -groupName: xyz
    -members
      -User1 = STATUS: "true"
      -User2 = STATUS: "pending"
  +group2
  +group3
  etc..

+Users
  -User1
    -Groups
      -group1 = STATUS: "true"
      -group3 = STATUS: "pending"
      etc..
  +User2
  +User3
  etc..
```

I'm trying to display group info to individual users based on whether they have a "true" or "pending" status. My app has separate page views for "pending" and "true" statuses.

Below is how I'm trying to achieve this.

```
.controller('GroupCtrl', function($scope, $firebaseObject, $rootScope) {
// Get a reference to the Firebase account
var fbRef = new Firebase("https://####.firebaseio.com/");
// Get a reference to where the User's Group IDs are stored
var fbUserCircle = new Firebase(fbRef + "/Users/" + $rootScope.fbAuthData.uid + "/Groups/");
var fbCircles = new Firebase(fbRef + "/Groups/");
var obj = $firebaseObject(fbUserCircle.orderByChild("Status").equalTo("pending"));

obj.$loaded().then(function() {
    console.log("loaded record:", obj.$id);

    // Iterating the key/value pairs of the object
    angular.forEach(obj, function(value, key) {

      var groupObj = $firebaseObject(fbCircles.child(key));
      console.log("$ref: " + circlesObj.$ref());    

      circlesObj.$loaded().then(function() {
          circlesObj.$bindTo($scope, "groups");
      })      
    })

})

})
```

In my page view I'm trying to display `{{groups.groupName}}` and `{{groups.groupMessage}}` over `ng-repeat` for a user who has groups with a "pending" status.

No data is being displayed in my view for displaying a user's group with "pending" statuses. What am I doing wrong? Anyone one know of a better way of doing this?

Comment: Wouldn't this best be done with [queries](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-queries)? Also, use $firebaseArray for collections, not $firebaseObject.

Comment: @Kato based on your comments I tried this: `fbUserCircle.orderByChild("Status").equalTo("pending").on('child_added', function(indexSnap) { var query = fbCircles.orderByChild("groupID").equalTo(indexSnap.key()); $scope.circles = $firebaseArray(query); });` Only the last record in the collection loads in my view, the rest is not showing up. Did I miss something?